# Error while starting Authserver.exe, it instanly crashes and says cannot conect to database

Tags: mysql

Hey boys can someone help me, im getting a error when i start auth server{

```
Error: http://prntscr.com/metncb
MySql: http://prntscr.com/metnqj
Authserver.conf.dist: http://prntscr.com/meto4w
```

Comment: I think you misspelled `Authserver` in your question. Correcting this may help more potential answerers find your question.

Comment: Done, thanks for the help